# Invalid AWS Code Artifact Policy Permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-codeartifact

Am not able to assign a policy to a repository which I created in AWS code artifact.

I am getting an error message **Policy document isn't a valid policy document**

Please help me in where i am going wrong.

Domain name = avc
Repo name = code-repo-maven-SNAPSHOT

````
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Action":[
            "codeartifact:*"
         ],
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Resource":"arn:aws:codeartifact:us-east-1:130000006255:repository/avc/code-repo-maven-SNAPSHOT"
      },
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":"sts:GetServiceBearerToken",
         "Resource":"*",
         "Condition":{
            "StringEquals":{
               "sts:AWSServiceName":"codeartifact.amazonaws.com"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}```
````

Answer (score 4):

Repository policy is **resource based** policy. It means it should have Principal.
[For more info](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/repo-policies.html)

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::130000006255:root"
            },
            "Action": "codeartifact:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:codeartifact:us-east-1:130000006255:repository/avc/code-repo-maven-SNAPSHOT"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: **Inspite of giving all permission**

 `aws codeartifact get-authorization-token --domain avc  --domain-owner 130000006255 --query authorizationToken --output text`

**is throwing**

`When calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: User: arn:aws:iam::130000006255:root is not authorized to perform: sts:GetServiceBearerToken on resource: arn:aws:iam::130000006255:root`

Which permission am i missing

Comment: I have added this policy both in domain level and repository level

Comment: Basically, its not a good practice to use root user. instead use IAM user.

Comment: Yeah, i agree this is just a POC, i am doing.  So i dont wanna create a iam user, is there way to get auth token?

Comment: create IAM user, use updated (answer)repository policy, follow https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/auth-and-access-control-iam-identity-based-access-control.html link which will help you create Identity based policy to use `sts:GetServiceBearerToken`.  Hope it helps.